# Spring boot 2 actuator without autoconfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-starter

Can anyone help me to figure out how to enable actuator endpoints without using autoconfiguration dependencies?

I'm working on a Spring-Boot 2 project but starter poms and autocnfiguration dependencies are forbidden.

Comment: Hello, @Lost_dev, have you found a sulution? Would be nice if you write an answer, as I've run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And add this on application.properties in order to enable all endpoints of actuator if you want enable all.

```
  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Comment: Thanks you Jonathan for your replay, but as I stated in the question starter POMs dependencies are not an option.